# How do I collect the maxim amount of records from an API?

Tags: python, api, dataframe, python-requests

I'm new in API world. Right now I'm using below code to receive data. In the end I make a data-frame of it and join it with multiple other data-frames to ultimately export it to MySQL. However it just returns me 250 records, when I run the same GET query in Postman and do a count I can see that there are for example 6500 records.

**This is my code:**

```
proxies = {'https': '***.***.***.com:***'}  
acces_token = "this_is_my_token"

headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + acces_token}    
mod_date =  'ModifiedOn gt 2010-01-01'   

params1 = {'$filter': mod_date, '$select': 'Field1, Field2}     
response1 = requests.get('https://***-***-***.***.com/odata/***', headers=headers, params=params1, proxies=proxies)

q1 = response1.json()
dictio1 = q1['value']

df1 = pd.DataFrame(dictio1)
print(df1)
```

**The output is:**

```
0   - Field 1 - Field 2
1   - x       - x
.   - x       - x
.   - x       - x
250 - x       - x
```

My aim is to build multiple loops for the multiple GET statements which collects all the 6500 records. After that I will merge those data-frames and place export them to MySQL.

**The expected output is:**

```
0     - Field 1 - Field 2
1     - x       - x
.     - x       - x
.     - x       - x
6500  - x       - x
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try to use the parameter `stream=True` in your get request.
If you set stream to True when making a request, Requests cannot release the connection back to the pool unless you consume all the data or call `Response.close`.

```
r = requests.get(..., stream=True)
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Hello Erwin. Thanks for the response, I added `stream=True` but still gets me the first 250 records. Is there something I can do with `next_link`?